# Is it legal/ok to use gravatar's random images?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gravatar

I don't want to use Gravatar for images that their users have uploaded, but rather JUST for the randomised default image it produes via the URL `http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/04d24379cd970b7670ee66fa203d646f?s=128&r=any&default=identicon&forcedefault=1` Is this legal to do ? Can't find anything in their TOS.

I originally wanted to use the Identicon Handler for ASP.NET but it's rife with errors.

Comment: Why not ask that question over at [gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/site/contact-us/)? They will be able to give a definite answer.

Comment: Why use Gravatar when you have [Unicorns](http://unicornify.appspot.com/)? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer.

According to https://en.gravatar.com/site/terms-of-service/:

> Use of the Services by Third Party Websites. Third party websites may
>   enable the use of the Services on their respective websites as
>   expressly authorized by Automattic (e.g., API calls into Gravatar:
>   http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement); provided that they (i) do not
>   copy, store or modify User Submissions; (ii) do not distribute,
>   display, perform, use or otherwise exercise or exploit any User
>   Submission or other user information for any purpose other than as
>   necessary to perform the Services for the applicable user; (iii) have
>   a privacy policy in effect and posted on such website that complies
>   with all applicable laws and regulations and that notifies such user
>   that it will only use personally identifiable information as set forth
>   in (ii) above; and (iv) agree to be bound by and comply with all the
>   terms, conditions, and limitations set forth in the Terms of Service
>   (“Gravatar-enabled website”).

So, assuming you do not claim it as yours, do not store it, do not modify it and agree to comply with the other terms and conditions, you should be OK.

Answer (score 3):

The random image that you try to use is made with the **Identicon**

Why not grab the code that generates them, and make the icons local on your server, and use them as you like.

The source code that make this images: http://identicon.codeplex.com/

Comment: I've tried it !!!!! GRR It's so buggy, there a problem with "parameter is not valid" and there's one smelly fix for it and it does not work lol

Comment: @Baconbeastnz Really is buggy ? I have use it and not remember any issue. Do not use the dll, use direct the source code. Its a "simple" icon generation at the `IdenticonRenderer`

Comment: @Baconbeastnz this code do the icon: 
http://identicon.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/3301#63540